# Movie about a rogue / martial artist brought to the present, rides a scooter at some point?

Tags: story-identification, movie, martial-arts

I sadly don't remember much about this one - hoping someone else can shed some light or at least add details to help the search.

This was a foreign-language movie whose main character was a 20-something man in a period martial arts setting. He was a rogue / thief / mischief maker, or at the very least had some misapplied skill in martial arts. Through some plot mechanism, he gets spirited away to a modern city, and spends some time trying to adapt to the new things he's seeing. I'm pretty sure there is another modern-day character involved in this, probably female, but I don't remember anything specific. Everyone in the movie was Asian and spoke the native language of that country (not confident enough to be more specific than that).

The other part I remember is a scene at the end, where he comes riding down the highway on a moped / scooter to save the day. I think he also ends up riding off into the sunset on the same scooter at the end? The scooter is a bit of a signature, it was on the movie poster and everything.

In general, I know it wasn't a full parody - but there were definitely some comedy / slapstick moments. Recent-ish, definitely not older than 10-15 years. Almost certain I watched it on netflix, if that helps. I'm hoping "period martial arts man riding a moped" is unique enough for someone to point me in the right direction, because google is convinced I'm talking about Bruce Lee.

**Another detail:** The MC may have been a minor noble / official of some kind, I remember him wearing dark single-colored robes and a hat in this style while he was perpetrating antics and when he first came to the modern world: https://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/jmnet/koreajoongangdaily/_data/photo/2019/02/18205313.jpg

**Another detail 2:** "From the past" was several centuries in the past. Not well-defined, but definitely feudal era. The MC had short- to medium-length hair (down to his neck at most), and no facial hair.

**Another detail 3:** I think the female counterpart is a civillian / office worker, she doesn't take part in the action much.

**What it isn't:** High fantasy - I'd put it more along the lines of Big Trouble in Little China (but more recent), or a Jackie Chan / Jet Li movie. More practical action than effects.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the pointers - I added language and ethnicity details, but I think I've answered most of these to the best of my ability otherwise

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO_DIwuGBnA

Comment: @Valorum Kung Fury is a personal favorite of mine, but sadly not what I'm looking for

Comment: Do you recall in what year you saw the movie and color of the moped or scooter?

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 unfortunately no - just a rough timeframe of within the last 10-15 years, and I don't remember the scooter color.

Comment: A few more questions, to further narrow things down: In roughly which year did you watch this movie? (Just to eliminate anything too recent.) Roughly which time period did the main character come from originally? (Was it the early 20th century, like in Ip Man, or multiple centuries in the past?) Also, did the main character have long hair or short hair, and did he have any facial hair?

Comment: @LogicDictates I can't really pin down a year, other than it wasn't in the last 6 years. Best guess is 2010-2015, but it is *very* guessy. MC came from multiple centuries in the past, short-to-medium hair, and no facial hair. Updated the info in the post too.

Comment: My bet was on Woochi also,  was the 1st movie that came to mind,  yet again no scooter. Unless your confusing 2 movie.

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 I'm beginning to suspect that's the case - it honestly wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might this be ***[Jeon Woo-chi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1274293/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2009) AKA *Woochi: the Demonslayer*...?

I don't think the hero rides a scooter in this, but it seems to match pretty much everything else you described.

> Jeon Woo-chi, an undisciplined womanizing Taoist from the Joseon era, ends up in present day Korea causing mayhem with his knack for magic.

Comment: Whoa! I'm almost certain this isn't it, it didn't have nearly as much high fantasy (I'm thinking more Big Trouble in Little China than The Forbidden Kingdom - but more recent). I'm definitely going to check this out though.

Comment: Also, worth noting that I thought you were right at first though - the MC is almost exacly what I was picturing.

Comment: @CodeMoose - Another user thought you might have been thinking of _[Bulletproof Monk](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245803/)_. I didn't think that was the right movie, since it isn't foreign language and most of the actors aren't Asian, but just to be sure, can you confirm whether that's the film you had in mind or not?

Comment: can confirm it's not Bulletproof Monk - I've got that one in my library already =)

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of another movie based on the legend of Woochi? The rascal wizard character is an exact fit, and a lot of this looks familiar - I'm just 100% sure I've never seen the rest of this movie.

Comment: Marking this as the answer - I'm pretty sure I'm blending to movies in my memory, as there is too much familiar here to ignore. Just means I get to watch it for the first time again!